# SQL How to sync aggregation table

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

Let's say I have 2 tables with the same structure.
A - users from France
B - users from Germany
They both have fields - id, name, salary.
C is aggregation table called WorldUsers.

When I change A or B, I want C to also change. When I change C, I want A and B to change.

What's the optimal way to do it?

Now my plan is:

1. Create table C with 2 foreign keys to A and B on field id (on delete cascade, on update cascade)
2. Create 2 foreign keys for A and B id's, linked to C
3. I guess that should work? But I wonder if that's the best way to do it, would like to hear feedback

Comment: Create a view C as the union of table A with table B, this means changes are automatically reflected in C.  If needed create a materialized view on C which refreshes periodically if the data volume is very large

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can think of doing this involves views.  This starts with creating `WorldUsers` as a view:

```
create view WorldUsers as
     select id, name, salary
     from france
     union all
     select id, name, salary
     from germany;
```

Then you can create a trigger on the view.  So, if one of the values changes, you can change the underlying table.

That said, I would question your entire premise for this data model.  Why not store all the data in one table with a country column?

```
create table WorldUsers (
    id int generated always as identity,
    name text,
    salary numeric,
    country text,
    check (country in ('france', 'germany'))
);
```

All updates would be on this table.  If you want to see users from a specific table, use a `where` clause.  Or, if you really want, create separate views for each country.

Comment: Thanks! I had this question during job interview, they asked how I would create a 3rd table like this from A and B. If we want to sync them manually, am I right we have to create a lot of triggers?

Like on update C - change A and B
on update A - change C
on update B - change C
the same for delete and insert

Comment: The way the task was formulated I think the view is not allowed, they meant 3 different tables

Comment: @Timur . . . I suspect you are just talking about a bunch of triggers in that case.  But that seems like a very bad application design.  Data normally should not be replicated like that.

Comment: And if we want to create a view, how to create triggers for deletion, insertion and update operations?

Comment: `create trigger` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).  `instead of` triggers work on views.

Comment: What if we want to be able to delete something from aggregation table C, and have it deleted from A and B? I guess that's not possible with views?

Comment: @Timur . . . It is possible with triggers.